# Axios put error 500 saying field cannot be empty

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So i am trying to update a user from the admin panel, i get the values from the form through a v-model and then i do my axios.put with all the data in a FormData(). The issue is that i get an error 500 saying that x field can't be empty, so i guess my FormData() isn't being passed on to the controller. 
I tried with a post method and it worked fine. So i wonder what i did wrong ?
Here's the Vuejs code :

```
<script>
export default {
    data () {
      return {
        search: '',
        headers: [
          { text: 'ID', align: 'start', value: 'id'},
          { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
          { text: 'Profile', value: 'profile' },
          { text: 'Email', value: 'email' },
          { text: 'Created At', value: 'created_at' },
          { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions' },
        ],
        users: null,
        editedUser: null,
        dialog: false,
      }
    },
    methods: {
        getUsers(){
            axios.get('../admin/getUsers')
        .then(response => this.users = response.data)
        },
        editUser(item){
          this.editedUser = item;
          this.dialog = true;
        },
        submitEditedUser(){
        let data = new FormData();

        data.append('id', this.editedUser.id)
        data.append('name', this.editedUser.name)
        data.append('profile', this.editedUser.profile)
        data.append('email', this.editedUser.email)

          axios.put('../admin/updateUser/' + this.editedUser.id, data)
          .then(res => {
          console.log('done');
          })
          .catch(err => {
          console.log('changes failed');
          })
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getUsers();
    }

  }
</script>
```

And here's the controller code :

```
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function updateUser($id, Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->name = request('name');
        $user->profile = request('profile');
        $user->email = request("email");

        $user->save();
    }
```

Everything works fine with post so nothing's wrong with the variable or the form, i think it really is just the data that's not being passed on. Although i want to use the put method because it is originally used for updating data.
Thanks !

Comment: cant you just use a raw javascript object for that `data` property you pass to `axios.put(...)`? FormData is usually only necessary for a mix of binary data and text data.

Answer (score -1):

can you try this? if this not work you can dd(request) inside the controller and see if is empty

```
public function updateUser($id, Request $request)
{

    $user = User::find($id);

    $user->name = $request->data['name'];
    $user->profile = $request->data['profile'];
    $user->email = $request->data['email'];

    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: I tried this and still got the same problem so i dd(request) and i can see the FormData with the right information.